# Custom toolbar compatible for IE Protected Mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, bho

I have created a custom toolbar for IE. I am placing my COM DLL in System32 folder. IE is able to load my toolbar in protected mode. My toolbar should read some data from ini file which is created in InternetCache folder. I am not registering my COM component to any category (e.g. CATID_AppContainerCompatible).

My question is

1) Is it compulsory to place the my DLL in sub folder of program files?

2) Do I need to register to app container category?

3) How can I make sure that my toolbar is compatible with protected mode.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

I used to develop a BHO for IE6+ before and hope you'll find those answers useful.

> 1) Is it compulsory to place the my DLL in sub folder of program files?

Don't remember exactly but if it's both signed and placed under a trusted location the more chances IE will pick it up.

> 2) Do I need to register to app container category?

Just registering a COM DLL module should be enough.

> 3) How can I make sure that my toolbar is compatible with protected mode.

It is by default but in protected mode you'll receive 'access denied' error on attempts of reading from or writing to many locations both on file system and in registry.

In registry you can use HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AppDataLow and %USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow on file system.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. My toolbar is reading some data from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\XXXXXX reg path and %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming folder. Registry value is read properly. Not sure about Roaming folder.